# Mclust : NAs in foreign function call (arg 13)

Tags: r, debugging, cluster-analysis

While trying to determine the optimal number of clusters for a kmeans, I tried to use the package `mclust` with the following code :

```
d_clust <- Mclust(df, 
                  G=1:10,      
                  mclust.options("emModelNames"))
d_clust$BIC
```

df is a data frame of 132656 obs. of 19 variables, the data is scaled, and there is no missing values (no `NA/NaN/Inf` values I checked with `is.na` and `is.finite`). Also, my variables are all in numeric format thanks to `as.numeric`

However after using the code, the screen displays "fitting" with a loading bar, goes up to 11%, and then after a moment I get the error message :

> NAs in foreign function call (arg 13)

Does anyone know why I have this type of error ?

### EDIT

Output of `str(df)` (I modified the variable name because of confidential issues)

```
'data.frame':   132656 obs. of  19 variables:

 $ X1: num  0.5 1 1 1 0.5 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ X2: num  0.714 0.286 1 0.857 0.286 ...
 $ X3: num  0.667 1 0.667 0.667 0.667 ...
 $ X4: num  0.714 0.429 1 0.714 0.429 ...
 $ X5: num  0.667 0.333 1 0.667 0.333 ...
 $ X6: num  0.5 0.25 1 0.5 0.25 0.25 0 0.5 0.5 0.25 ...
 $ X7: num  0.667 0.667 0.667 0.667 0.667 ...
 $ X8: num  0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 ...
 $ X9: num  0.667 0 0.667 0.333 0 ...
 $ X10: num  1 0.833 1 1 1 ...
 $ X11: num  1 0.75 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ X12: num  1 1 1 0.8 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ X13: num  0.5 0.75 0.75 0.5 0.75 0.25 0.75 0.5 0.5 0.5 ...
 $ X14: num  0.75 0.75 0.75 1 0.75 0.75 0.75 1 0.75 0.75 ...
 $ X15: num  1 0 0.5 1 1 1 0.75 1 0.5 1 ...
 $ X16: num  1 0.333 0.667 0.833 0.833 ...
 $ X17: num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ X18: num  0.00157 0.000438 0.001059 0.000879 0.004919 ...
 $ X19: num  0.5 0.125 1 0.625 0.125 0.125 0.125 1 0.5 0.25 ...
```

Comment: Have you checked if there are NAs after as.numeric? Try `any(is.na(as.numeric(df)))`. In addition, could you post the output of `str(df)` ?

Comment: @MarcoSandri : Yes I checked there isn't NA's after. I also editer my Q to add the output of `str(df)`

Comment: @MarcoSandri: `Error in mvnXII(data = data, prior = prior) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)`

Comment: @MarcoSandri: It work fine, I get `'Mclust' model object:
 best model: ellipsoidal multivariate normal (XXX) with 1 components`

Comment: @MarcoSandri :It still works for a subset of 10000 observations, I'm trying to increase this number little by little until I find an approximate position of the problem (I guess)

Comment: @MarcoSandri: It appears that after 40000 observations, there is a problem that occurs

Comment: Sometimes I get the error message. Sometimes, the program just keeps running for a long time before RStudio Session terminates

Comment: May be this a  problem of mclust with "big" datasets. Last experiment. Try to input into mclust a matrix of random numbers with > 40000 rows and 19 columns.

Comment: Seems like you're right : After several tries RStudio just keeps aborting... Seems like I'll have to find another way to determine the optimal cluster number ; you can do a proper answer, I'll gladly accept it as a thanks for you help

Comment: Any chance you have binary variables?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse My 17th variable is indeed composed of only 0's and 1's

Comment: Binary (or discrete with very few levels - you also have several discrete variables) could cause problems. If all data in a cluster has the same value (theoretically, this never happens, but in reality it can) you get zero variance, and Gaussian density computation fails. Then you can get unexpected NAs. For this reason, GMM on discrete/binary variables should not be used (and obviously, **such variables cannot be Gaussian** - it's the wrong model for such data.)